# Issue with missing artifacts in a Maven/Spring project

Tags: java, spring, rest, pom.xml

I'm trying to learn REST with a Spring/Maven context and so I'm going through a Pankaj Kumar (JournalDev) tutorial.  I set up a Spring project in STS (Spring Tool Suite), and according to the tutorial, I will need to include the following dependencies: jackson-databind, jackson-core, and jackson-annotations. I declared them in the pom.xml editor in STS.

I wanted to include the actual XML from the POM.xml file, everytime I tried to submit the question, I got the error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly" and it would allow me to submit this posting at all.  It's not code, it's XML and I did indent by 4 spaces per the instructions.  If you need to see the actual XML, please tell how to get around this issue with StackOverflow and I will gladly include the actual XML.

I get three errors in the POM.xml file:

```
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:bundle:2.5.3
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:bundle:2.5.3
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:bundle:2.5.3
```

Basically, everything looks good to the extent of my knowledge in this situation.  Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you tried running a `mvn clean` ?

Comment: It would help with the pom.xml file. Maybe if you send it in a PM to me and I see what I can do with an edit.

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the dependency type to `bundle`?  If you are, remove those lines.

Comment: I closed STS and ran mvn clean in the project root directory (BTW, can i run mvn clean from within STS?)  Running the command was partially successful.  Now the only error is: "Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:bundle:2.5.3".  the other two have gone away.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding pom.xml error, You will get it when added dependencies are not updated in .m2 repository. Try it by deleting .m2 repository after closing STS. After deleting is finished, open STS and do the maven -> Update Project, it will update .m2 repository automatically.

Comment: The Update project certainly rebuild the .m2 repository and it looked like success for about 20 seconds and then the error came back.  Is there a missing step?

Comment: Actually rebuilding .m2 repository takes more time. Repeat the procedure again and do complete Project clean. Hope it will work for you. I have faced similar issue couple of times and it had worked for me.